# Lightning Web Component embedded in Visualforce Page via Aura Component and App not displaying

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I am writing a lightning web component that is going to be used in Salesforce Classic, Lightning Experience and an Employee Community. It does not HAVE to be a lightning web component - I could use a traditional Aura Lightning Component if I must.

However, what I am finding is that the visualforce page does not work, even when the lwc component is embedded in a aura component that is then used with Lightning Components for Visualforce. I can see from the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/get_started_supported_experiences) that using a lwc directly from within visualforce is not supported, but I was under the impression that it may work if wrapped in an aura component.

My question then is this:

**Has anyone had success having a lwc wrapped in an aura component display successfully within Visualforce? Or is this completely unsupported behaviour?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Summer 19 release, now its possible to use LWC in visualforce as lightning out.

https://www.paul-force.com/2019/04/24/use-lightning-web-components-in-visualforce-pages/
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lwc_vf.htm

Comment: But is it possible to use Visualforce components within LWC?

Answer (score 3):

It is not supported behavior. While some standard components are actually LWC, they are given an exception (otherwise Lightning Out would be useless). For now, *custom* LWC are not supported in an unsupported environment, no matter how you dress it up.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sfdcfox. I suppose there is no mention anywhere of whether they intend to support this in the future? This sounds like I will need to go back to using an Aura component for the front end for this component.

Comment: @bpilling I personally hope that they will, but I do not know if or when such support would be coming. You might try asking on Twitter if anyone knows and is willing to share.

Comment: I decided to just rewrite the component in Aura - and that has worked fine. Most of the heavy lifting was in the apex controller anyway, so in my case it's unfortunate, but not a big deal I have had to go back to an Aura component.

Answer (score 1):

When I wrapped up the LWC into the Aura Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">
    <div>This is AURA component</div>
    <c:lwcComponent/>
</aura:component>
```

and Use Aura App with Lightning Out

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:auraComponent"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:showToast" type="EVENT"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToURL" type="EVENT"/>
</aura:application>
```

I was able to enable it on the visualforce page in classic

```
$Lightning.use("c:auraApp", function() {
  $Lightning.createComponent("c:auraComponent",
  { 
      recordId: ...,
      sObjectName: ...
  },
  "auraApp",
  ....
```

Comment: Looks like I will need to revisit this and see if I am doing something wrong. If it is working for you chances are I've done something wrong - so thank you for posting your code.

Comment: Just found this comment for the tile lwc in the LWC Component Library:
Usage Considerations
    Icons are not available in Lightning Out, but they are available in Lightning 
    Components for Visualforce and other experiences.
Which suggests that Lightning Components for Visualforce is supported?